# How do i check if a logo is in a BMP file?

Tags: python, image-processing

can anybody give me advice how i process a BMP file so 
that i can check if a logo is present in that file?

E.g. I have a Foto.  My logo is supplied in another 
bmp file. I want to check if my logo is part of that
foto, if it is visible.

Bonus question: My logo can have transparencies in it. 
Does that change anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is quite a sophisticated procedure. The keyword you want to use is probably not "digital watermarking" (which is correct per se, but will return mostly hits about how to watermark a picture) but **"image recognition"** (which is a broader concept, but describes the process in the other direction, i.e. *recognising* if the logo is already there).

For example a StackOverflow search returns [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1603688/146792), with a load of useful hints and tips.

The bottom line (whether you are going to use a library or implement yourself a solution) is that you have first to transform your image in a numerical 2-dimensional array, and then do a number of transformations/analysis to spot signs that hints about the presence of your logo.

You might also be interested to check the [python bindings for OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/cookbook.html) (*the* computer vision library of the free software world). OpenCV is probably overkilling the problem you are facing, but OTOH it has extensive documentation and examples.

HTH!

Comment: the problem here is not trivial and there is no way openCV is overkill for this. It could be constructed from other librarires such as Leptonica, but openCV is the tool for this case.

Comment: hm you could earn another upvote with an example, that tells me how to acess pixels in opencv xD. Then i could implement easier :)

Comment: @tarrasch - Appreciate the offer, but SO is not a crowdsourcing site, it's a Q&A platform: you should give it a try yourself and then, if you get stuck somewhere, come back and post a new question showing [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Answer (score 1):

Read up your favorite literature on the subject of **digital watermarking**.
It's not trivial if you want it to be robust to various distortions, image compression, transparency, etc. - nothing I can answer here in a few lines.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but maybe [imgSeek](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/imgSeek/0.8.6) can be of any help (content-based search of images is one of the features).

Answer (score -2):

Bonus answer: if you what the logo with a transparent background let say no background use a .png or .gif file, if you want 20% transparencies u can use CSS Image Opacity / Transparency or save you logo as a png with a transparent filter you can do this in adobe fireworks

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the question. The OP is asking how to *check* if the logo is on the picture, not how to *put* it...