# Image outline using python/PIL

Tags: python-imaging-library

I have a color photo of apple, how can I show only its outline (inside white, background black) with python/PIL?

Comment: Include some sample image of expected input.

Answer (score 30):

Something like this should work.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

image = Image.open('your_image.png')
image = image.filter(ImageFilter.FIND_EDGES)
image.save('new_name.png')
```

If that doesn't give you the result you are looking for then you try implementing either Prewitt edge detection, Sobel edge detection or Canny edge detection using PIL and Python and other libraries see related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603688/python-image-recognition) and the following [example](http://cyroforge.wordpress.com/2012/01/21/canny-edge-detection/) .

If you are trying to do particle detection / analysis rather than just edge detection, you can try using [py4ij](http://code.google.com/p/py4ij/) to call the ImageJ method you link to give you expect the same result, or try another Particle Analysis Python library [EMAN](http://www.msg.ucsf.edu/local/programs/eman/index.html) alternately you can write a Particle detection algorithm using PIL, SciPy and NumPy.

Comment: Hi, 
The photos are in color and even when I gray-scale them and run the filters it does not work fine as I just want the outline of the apple shape, is it possible? 

It is something like the imageJ method described in  rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/docs/pdfs/examples.pdf.

Thanks

Comment: @Appleman1234, thank you so much for referring to my post. Hey, you can import the canny edge detection modules and run it to find the edges alone. The output will be a numpy ndarray, but you can convert into PIL image using im = Image.fromarray(imarray)

Comment: @Appleman is it possible to split the image into components based on FIND_EDGES?

Answer (score 4):

If your object and background have fairly well contrast

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open(your_image_file)
mask=image.convert("L")
th=150 # the value has to be adjusted for an image of interest 
mask = mask.point(lambda i: i < th and 255)
mask.save(file_where_to_save_result)
```

if higher contrast is in one (of 3 colors), you may split the image into bands instead of converting it into grey scale.

if an image or background is fairly complicated, more sophisticated processing will be required

Answer (score 1):

[Apple vs Lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sN9qU.jpg)
You can do it just using PIL and Python in less than 200  lines of code.  Would be easier to use canny-edge-detection from a library.
Here is the steps.  Convert to grayscale for lumens.  Using kernel image processing detect edges using Sobel. Thin the edge using the magnitude and slope obtain from Sobel.

```
from PIL import Image
import math


def one_to_two_dimension_array(list_,columns):
    #use list slice
    return [ list_[i:i+columns] for i in range(0, len(list_),columns) ] 

def flatten_matrix(matrix):
    return [val for sublist in matrix for val in sublist]

def matrix_convole(matrix, kernel_matrix, multiplier):
    return_list=[]
    return_matrix=[]

    border=(len(kernel_matrix) - 1) / 2;border=int(border)
    center_kernel_pos=border
    for matrix_row in range( len( matrix )):
        for matrix_col in range(len( matrix[matrix_row] ) ):
            accumulator = 0
            if (matrix_row - border)<0 or \
            (matrix_col-border)< 0 or \
            (matrix_row+border) > (len( matrix )-border) or \
            (matrix_col+border) > (len( matrix[matrix_row] )-border):
                return_list.append(matrix[matrix_row][matrix_col])
                continue
            for kernel_row in range(len (kernel_matrix) ):
                for kernel_col in range(len (kernel_matrix[kernel_row]) ):      

                    relative_row= kernel_row - center_kernel_pos
                    relative_col= kernel_col - center_kernel_pos
                    kernel = kernel_matrix[kernel_row][kernel_col]
                    pixel = matrix [matrix_row + relative_row] [matrix_col + relative_col]
                    accumulator += pixel * kernel
            return_list.append(accumulator* multiplier )
    return_matrix = one_to_two_dimension_array( return_list, len( matrix[0] ) )
    return return_matrix
            
def canny_round_degree(deg):
    #0, 22.5, 45, 67.5, 90, 112.5, 135, 157.5, 180

    if deg >= 0 and deg <= 22.5:
        return 0
    elif deg >= 22.5 and deg <= 67.5:
        return 45
    elif deg > 67.5 and deg <=112.5:
        return 90
    elif deg > 112.5 and deg <=157.5:
        return 135
    elif deg >= 157.5 and deg <= 180:
        return 0

    if deg <= 0 and deg >= -22.5:
        return 0
    elif deg <= -22.5 and deg >= -67.5:
        return 135
    elif deg < -67.5 and deg >= -112.5:
        return 90
    elif deg < -112.5 and deg >= -157.5:
        return 45
    elif deg <= -157.5 and deg >= -180:
        return 0

image_path='apple.jpg'
gaussian_5x5_kernel=[[2,4,5,4,2],[4,9,12,9,4],[5,12,15,12,5],[4,9,12,9,4],[2,4,5,4,2]] #multiplier 1/159
sobel_kernel_gx=[[-1,0,1],[-2,0,2],[-1,0,1]]
sobel_kernel_gy=[[-1,-2,-1],[0,0,0],[1,2,1]] 
im_list=list(Image.open(image_path).convert('L').getdata(0)) #grayscale, get first channel
im_width=Image.open(image_path).width
im_height=Image.open(image_path).height
im_matrix = one_to_two_dimension_array(im_list, im_width)

im_matrix_blur=matrix_convole(im_matrix,gaussian_5x5_kernel, 1/159)

sobel_gx_matrix=matrix_convole(im_matrix_blur,sobel_kernel_gx, 1)
sobel_gy_matrix=matrix_convole(im_matrix_blur,sobel_kernel_gy, 1)

sobel_gy_list=flatten_matrix(sobel_gy_matrix) 
sobel_gx_list=flatten_matrix(sobel_gx_matrix) 

sobel_g_magnitude_list = [math.hypot(gy,gx) for gx,gy in zip(sobel_gx_list,sobel_gy_list)]


sobel_g_angle_list = [ canny_round_degree(math.degrees(math.atan2(gy,gx))) for gx,gy in zip(sobel_gx_list,sobel_gy_list)]

sobel_g_angle_matrix = one_to_two_dimension_array(sobel_g_angle_list, im_width)
sobel_g_magnitude_matrix = one_to_two_dimension_array(sobel_g_magnitude_list, im_width)
suppression_list = []
for s_row in range( len( sobel_g_angle_matrix)):
    for s_col in range(len( sobel_g_angle_matrix[s_row] ) ):
        if (s_row - 1)<0 or \
            (s_col-1)< 0 or \
            (s_row+1) > (len( sobel_g_angle_matrix )-1) or \
            (s_col+1) > (len( sobel_g_angle_matrix[s_row] )-1):
            suppression_list.append(0)
            continue
    
        magnitude_in_question = sobel_g_magnitude_matrix[s_row][s_col]
        #thresholding magnitude continue, arbitrary 129
        if magnitude_in_question < 36:
            suppression_list.append(0)
            continue    

        angle_in_question = sobel_g_angle_matrix[s_row][s_col]

        east_magnitude = sobel_g_magnitude_matrix[s_row][s_col-1]
        west_magnitude = sobel_g_magnitude_matrix[s_row][s_col+1]
        north_magnitude = sobel_g_magnitude_matrix[s_row-1][s_col]
        south_magnitude = sobel_g_magnitude_matrix[s_row+1][s_col]
        north_east_magnitude = sobel_g_magnitude_matrix[s_row-1][s_col-1]
        north_west_magnitude = sobel_g_magnitude_matrix[s_row-1][s_col+1]
        south_east_magnitude = sobel_g_magnitude_matrix[s_row+1][s_col-1]
        south_west_magnitude = sobel_g_magnitude_matrix[s_row+1][s_col+1]       
        if angle_in_question == 0 and magnitude_in_question > east_magnitude \
            and magnitude_in_question > west_magnitude:
            suppression_list.append(1)  
        elif angle_in_question == 90 and magnitude_in_question > north_magnitude \
            and magnitude_in_question > south_magnitude:
            suppression_list.append(1)  
        elif angle_in_question == 135 and magnitude_in_question > north_west_magnitude \
            and magnitude_in_question > south_east_magnitude:
            suppression_list.append(1)  
        elif angle_in_question == 45 and magnitude_in_question > north_east_magnitude \
            and magnitude_in_question > south_west_magnitude:
            suppression_list.append(1)  
        else:
            suppression_list.append(0)  
            

new_img = Image.new('1', (im_width,im_height)) #bw=1;grayscale =L
new_img.putdata( suppression_list )
new_img.save('apple-lines.png', 'PNG')
```