# Open Source way to real-time image processing OCR application?

Tags: image-processing, open-source, computer-vision, ocr

I have an application in mind that I want to produce.  We have wall-mounted schedule boards that are divided into small rectangles using black lines on a white background.  Magnetic name tags are placed into a particular partition to indicate this person is to work in that cell.  This system works very well for communication among people, but I would like an automatic way of saving this schedule information into a database automatically.

I am envisioning a system where a camera is set in a fix position focusing on the schedule board.  Periodically the camera will take a picture of the board.  I want to write some code to decipher which name tags are in which area.  This would require some OCR or symbol recognition.  There are big numbers on each name tag that I will use to identify the person whose name tag it is.

I naturally go to Python when tackling a new programming problem.  I found this post -> [python image recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603688/python-image-recognition) which looks like a good place to start (with PIL and numpy).

Do you know a good way to do this?

Update:  I have tried SimpleCV and it seems good for now.

Comment: You could, I think, make your task easier if you added a bar code to the name tags or wrote the numbers in a font designed to ease OCR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a pretty hard problem, even though it looks quite simple. But you can make it a lot easier by doing some stuff to your image to make this manageable. I have the following suggestions:

- Try to make it so that your camera is looking straight at the board with a reasonable lens so that there is minimal distortion of the image on the edges, and no perspective distortion.
- Given that you'll be shooting the occasional image for analysis I think performance is in no way an issue, so shoot high-resolution images, with a flash or with a long exposure time (because everything you're shooting is stationary) to get the best possible picture quality.
- If the number of different tags you expect is not too large you might find it easier to just try to match reference images of these tags in your image through [template matching](http://opencv-code.com/Template_Matching_with_OpenCV) rather than going for full OCR of numbers. This is a lot easier to get working if your image is good enough. The [python opencv interface](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/PythonInterface) is very complete.
- High Performance Mark has a good comment to your question about including [barcodes](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/) on the tags. I would add the option of [QR codes](http://pyqrcode.sourceforge.net/), but that is just the same thing. Both are easy to detect and there are good libraries to help you read them.
- If you decide you do need OCR, you should look into available OCR packages and not try to roll your own. Try [pytesser](https://code.google.com/p/pytesser/) for the [tesseract](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) engine or the [OCRopus](https://code.google.com/p/ocropus/) [python interface](https://code.google.com/p/ocropus/wiki/LibraryReference).

Comment: From my experience with a very similar image capture set-up, flash is often very unhelpful if the surface you are trying to photograph is highly reflective as, for example, most whiteboards are, and the flash is located at the same place as the camera.  But good illumination, however come by, is most useful.

Comment: Yes, if you use a flash you should position is so that reflections b do not  become an issue. In general you should start with as good an image as you can get.

Comment: I like the idea of bar codes or QR codes.  Perhaps a distinct border for each tag with a bar code.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned that you would like to use Python for this problem, perhaps you could take a look at [SimpleCV](http://simplecv.org/). It will provides you an easy way to grab the image from the camera and do basic image processing.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly agree with jilles de witt that OCR would be an extremely hard image analysis task to develop from scratch.  Code reading would be a better option, but that also will be difficult to program and will require sophisticated or somewhat challenging imaging as others have noted.  However, for this app you really do not need to implement OCR or formal bar codes, QR or other 2d codes.

Since your application is constrained to a limited number of targets, perhaps you could make your own simple code.  For example, you could place 0 to 4 big dots in a 2x2 array after each person's name.  This simple example code uniquely identifies 16 unique tags, and the features will be much easier to image, extract and decode than formal codes. Add a locator line if the code position is not consistent.